# Enabled Intel Virtualization Technology is not turned on

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, haxm

Actually I am trying to launch the AVD emulator in Android Studio. The Problem: "Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD".

I know that this is a common problem, however none of the existing answers I found could solve my problem:

- I enabled "Intel Virtualization Technology" in the BIOS
- VT-d is Enabled
- The NX-Disable-bit is Enabled
- The status of Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) is "Installed"
- In "Turn Windows Features on or off" I did not find Hyper-V, I tried to disable it using dism.exe but dism did not find it either
- I have Avast installed, but the Hardware Acceleration setting is UNchecked
- I ran the intelhaxm-android.exe, but "Remove" was the only clickable option
- I downloaded the lates intel HAXM version from the intel site, but during the installation process the message "This computer meets the requirements for HAXM, but Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on"

At the moment I am really frustrated since it seems that these steps worked for the vast majority. I would be really happy about any kind of help.

**UPDATE**:
With the help of Dhinakaran I was able to find in the task manager:

> Virtualization: Deactivated
>
> Hyper-V-Support: Yes

My OS is Windows 10 Home.

Comment: Are you using last version of Android Studio? Older installers of "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)" used to need an extra step after "installing" it (so, they needed an extra step to *enable* it). My current version is 6.2.1.

Comment: It's not "NX-bit" in the BIOS, it's hardware virtualization you want.  AKA VT-x and VT-d.  (x86-64 requires that support for the NX bit in page tables be present.)

Comment: My haxm installer is version 6.2.1, my Android Studio is version 3.0.1

Comment: Setting the NX-bit was suggested in an answer I found elsewhere. Intel Virtualization Technology and VT-d are both Enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt as Administrator `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V` this will disable hyper-v and restart

Comment: As I mentioned in my post I already tried this. dism exits with the error code 0x800f080c and "feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown".

Comment: you get any error  while install or update sdk. check your AndroidSDK-> extras->intel folder you will find haxm folder. if it exist than unistall haxm  and install it using Android sdk manager

Comment: The folder exists. I now clicked on "Remove" in the haxm installer, but how should I install it with Android SDK manager? I thought Android Studio just installs the installer -- should I reinstall the installer?

Comment: goto sdk manager -> sdk tools you find intelx86 emulkator accelerator click check box and apply

Comment: if your deleted the hxam folder uncheck and apply. than again click install

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. See update in original post for details

Comment: if you have antivirus disable

Comment: i'm told you to uninstall HAXM and install not to delete folder edit you update correctly

Comment: Disabling the antivirus didn't help either.

Comment: Sorry, I may have misinterpreted "if your deleted the hxam folder uncheck and apply.".

Comment: check my another answer it will work i have verified

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your emulator Requirements in https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html
2. Check virtualiztion support in https://www.shaileshjha.com/how-to-find-out-if-intel-vt-x-or-amd-v-virtualization-technology-is-supported-in-windows-10-windows-8-windows-vista-or-windows-7-machine/

If you want to install HAXM go to windows Apps & Feature uninstall intel Hardware Accellerated Execution manager. And open android studio open sdk manager and install haxm now it will install without error

Comment: First of all a quick thanks for trying to help me :)
All requirements mentioned in the first link are met, however the second link helped a bit. I looked in the task manager and according to it Virtualization is Deactivated.